# Spring Boot Spring Data JPA JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: jpa, jboss, spring-data-jpa

> 16:57:41,389 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 86) Application startup failed:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;

I am deploying a .war file in JBoss EAP 6.4

I am using Spring Boot version '1.2.4.RELEASE'

I have tried:

1. Creating a jboss-deployment-structure.xml with:

   ```
   <jboss-deployment-structure>
       <deployment>
           <exclude-subsystems>
               <subsystem name="jpa" />
           </exclude-subsystems>
           <exclusions>
               <module name="javax.persistence.api" />
               <module name="org.hibernate"/>
           </exclusions>
       </deployment>
   </jboss-deployment-structure>
   ```
2. **Note:** excluding the module  `javaee.api` creates more exceptions
3. Also, changed standalone.xml to remove the jpa subsystem:

   ```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
       <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
   </subsystem>
   ```
4. Also changed `/middleware/jboss64/modules/system/layers/base/javaee/api/main/module.xml`:

   ```
   <module name="javax.persistence.api" export="false"/>
   ```
5. I can see from the Spring Boot 1.2.4.RELEASE Documentation -

> org.springframework.data          spring-data-jpa
>   1.7.2.RELEASE

6. I can see in the `spring-data-jpa 1.7.x pom.xml` :

   ```
   <hibernate>3.6.10.Final</hibernate>
   ```

But the war file was generated using gradle 2.4 contains  `Hibernate-core-4.3.8.jar` and `hibernate-jpa-2.1-1.0.0.jar`, why ?

The only theory I have is that JBoss is inserting its own Jpa jar and NOT the hibernate jar which cause mismatch of the Hibernate and jpa API causing the exception.

7. I think downgrading the the Hibernate version in spring boot project will fix this mismatch, so I changed build.gradle ...

   ```
   configurations.all {
       resolutionStrategy {
           eachDependency {
               if (it.requested.group == 'org.hibernate') {  
                   it.useVersion '4.2.19.Final'
               }
           }
       }
   ```

I got following error

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration
>   ':callcentre2:compile'.  Could not resolve
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.2.19.Final.
>
> ( ....some https url here but I cant write it here cos stackoverflow
>   does not let me save the question)

Am I on the right track to downgrade the Hibernate version if so how do I fix the above build error? What is the repo for Hibernate?

**Update:**

I fixed the above by including ...

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        // Use Hibernate 4.2
        if (details.requested.name == "hibernate-core") {
            details.useTarget "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.2.19.Final"
        }
        if (details.requested.name == "hibernate-entitymanager") {
            details.useTarget "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.2.19.Final"
        }
        // Use JPA 2.0
        if (details.requested.name == "hibernate-jpa-2.1-api") {
            details.useTarget "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final"
        }
    }
}
```

But now I am getting on the JBoss EAP 6.4 :

> Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link
>   org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/hibernate/SpringJtaPlatform (Module
>   "deployment.callcentre2.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
>           ... 31 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/transaction/jta/platform/internal/AbstractJtaPlatform
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
>           ... 53 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform
>   from [Module "deployment.callcentre2.war:main" from Service Module
>   Loader]